# Anonymizing Tor Proxy as virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, proxy

I'm just wandering if its possible to create a virtual machine dedicated as a Tor proxy a bit like this hardware solution: [Onion Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi?view=all)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Whonix for example, which is a ready-to-run virtual machine that acts as a tor proxy.

All the details on how to do this is here:
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Other_Operating_Systems

Comment: Ill give it a look definitely. I managed to integrate Tor to pfSense but a more flexible solution would be prefered. Hopefully, your solution will provide that.